# How to get pre-selected combo box value from combo box?

Tags: combobox, vb6

Here as you can see I'm not using combox_click because it is declared above and the current one is another function to be called without clicking, here my question is how do I get the pre-selected value from the combo box without clicking on the box?

```
   Public Sub ComDep_Change()
        Dim sQuery As String
        Dim oRS As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim rsPR As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim dateFormat As String
        Dim sPONO As String
        Dim sPOAmt As String
        'oRS.Open "po_receiveable", PRCnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
        combVal = ComDep.List(ComDep.ListIndex)
        If Not combVal = "ALL_DEPT" And frmMain.OptLatestCN.Value = True Then
            'MsgBox ("Works")
            dateFormat = "#" + CStr(Day(Now)) + "/" + CStr(Month(Now)) + "/" + CStr(Year(Now) - 3) + "#"
            sQuery = "select * from CN_Request_Header where dept = '" & combVal & "' and requestdate >= " & dateFormat & ""
    '        sQuery = "Select PO_No, PO_Requestor, PO_Req_Dept, PO_Status, PO_Approval_M, PO_Approval_GM, PO_Approval_D, PO_HRApproval, VC_No, TH_Sup_Inv, PO_HR_Rmk, PO_Req_Date, PO_SupplierName, PO_OverallAmt from PR_INFO where PO_Req_Dept = '" & combVal & "'"
    '        MsgBox ("Result" & sQuery)
            rsPR.Open sQuery, PRCnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
            lvwCreditNote.ListItems.Clear

            Do While Not rsPR.EOF
            Set listitem = frmMain.lvwCreditNote.ListItems.Add
            With listitem
                .Text = CStr(Trim(rsPR!requestID))
                .SubItems(1) = Trim(rsPR!requestID)
                .SubItems(2) = Format(CStr(rsPR!requestdate), "dd-mmm-yy")
                .SubItems(3) = Trim(rsPR!createby)
                .SubItems(4) = Trim(rsPR!dept)
                .SubItems(5) = Trim(rsPR!reqstatus)
                If IsNull(rsPR!custName) Then
                    .SubItems(6) = ""
                Else
                    .SubItems(6) = Trim(rsPR!custName)
                End If
                If IsNull(rsPR!cnamt) Then
                    .SubItems(7) = "0.00"
                Else
                    .SubItems(7) = Format(rsPR!cnamt, "#,###,##0.00")
                End If
```

Comment: How about ComDep.Text?

Answer (score 0):

You would get the currently ***SELECTED*** element in a combobox 
by using the ***SELECTEDINDEX***  Property

If nothing is selected then you get the value ***-1*** returned to you.
If something is selected it will be in the range  ***0 to Combox.Count - 1***

To get the text for the selected item
You could use something like...

```
Dim SelIndex as Integer
Dim SelText As String
'
SelIndex = MyCombobox.SelectedIndex
If (SelIndex >= 0) AND (SelIndex <= MyCombobox.Count - 1) Then
   SelText = MyCombobox.List(Index)
Else
   'Nothing was selected in the combobox
End If
```

Comment: Hi @Zeddy, thanks for reaching out my post, are you sure SelectedIndex is works within VB6? I had tried and it doesnt work.